# Customization in video view

Tags: java, android

I got a question here regarding in Android Studio (using Java). Is there any way possible that without using the `VideoView` widget, you can play video?

And if not then how do I change the `VideoView` visually.

I meant by adding different kind of buttons to it and adding different functionality to it. Like seeking, 10 sec forward or backward or something like that(I know that we can do it using the inbuilt one, but why not try it in the custom way) and all other kind of functionality we use when we play video on VLC kind of player.

So, if there anything like that, I would be grateful to hear about that!.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). It's easy and more customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Use Media player with custom controls please go through attached link once [Media Player with custom controls](https://github.com/nagorbasha/Custom-Media-Controller)